# Is there a command to get the list of tagged and untagged VLANs in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

Is there a command to get the list of tagged and untagged VLANs in Ubuntu? While creating a VLAN using `vconfig` or `ip link` command, we are not specifying whether the VLAN is tagged/untagged. Also I am unable to find out whether the VLAN is tagged or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at your routers port configuration to see which tagged VLANs it allows through to your computer, and what - if any - VLAN is set as default untagged.

The traffic you get through on eth0 (or similar) is fro untagged / default VLAN. Traffic on eth0.xxx is from VLAN xxx.